# LSTM in python : Value Error : Data cardinality is ambiguous

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am a newbie in machine learning and wanted to implement the LSTM neural network in order to classify cars speed profiles.

So in the end I have car speed data from a road segment and I want the algorithm to classify them in categories. Depending on the state of traffic and traffic lights, the number of records in the end differ from a vehicle to another one. If the vehicle passes the segment quickly and without stopping, the speed records would be few, and if it takes a long time to traverse the segment, the speed records would numerous. The vehicles record their velocities once every second.

The problem I encounter states that the cardinality of the data is ambiguous, which is beyond the point, I have chosen the LSTM precisely because the data I have doesn't have the same size.

My code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
import fileLayout as fl


tf.random.set_seed(7)

filename = "segmentedData.csv"
csv = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = fl.delimeter)

filename = "Clusters.csv"
clstr = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = fl.delimeter)

csv = csv[csv["segment"] == "T1"]

stations = csv["fullID"].drop_duplicates()
stations = [station for station in stations]

x = []
y = []

for station in stations :
    clcsv = csv[csv["fullID"] == station]
    clcsv = clcsv["speedvalue"].to_numpy()
    x.append(clcsv)
    ytemp = clstr[clstr["stationId"] == station]
    ytemp = ytemp["class"].iloc[0]
    y.append(ytemp)
    
y = np.asarray(y).astype(np.int)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

The error I get :

`ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 17, 20, 5, 20, 17, 45, 21, 60, 8, 6, 28, 51, 6, 40, 78, 73, 66, 26, 32, 8, 12, 11, 22, 10, 36, 84, 2, 11, 18, 31, 32, 8, 25, 20, 17, 36, 11, 11, 4, 14, 18, 8, 46, 53, 19, 34, 13, 25, 38, 20, 11, 14, 27, 29, 56, 43, 31, 130, 63, 184, 13, 13, 32, 22, 14, 12, 10, 23, 35, 17, 34 y sizes: 71 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.`

Using LSTMs I was expecting to be able to plug data with different cardinalilty but it doesn't work. I have tried messing with the types, throwing various data structure types such as lists and arrays, it only seems to work with an x of type list and y of type np.array, otherwise I get the following error :

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Comment: you have car speed data.  the car speed and segment is given.  from the speed of the vehicle you are trying to determine a classification.  are you expecting to find groupings of vehicles that travel as certain speeds?

Comment: Indeed, clusters of trips that share the same speed profiles. For example the first cluster groups trips in which the vehicles didn't stop for traffic light and the second cluster for vehicles that did.

Comment: where is the csv located to try clustering the data?  I think you could do data discovery and see if there are hot spots of groupings.

Comment: Could you please try running your code again by changing the type of the x and y dataset as 'float32' using `x= np.asarray(x).astype('float32')`, `y= np.asarray(y).astype('float32')`.